# Comparing two large lists to find element pairs that meet a condition in python

Tags: python, list, element

I have two large lists of numbers (maybe a million elements each). I would like to compare both of them element-wise to identify element pairs that have a difference of less than 0.5. I know two nested for loops is not an option. Is there any quick way to do this using sets or zip?

For eg. if my lists are `list1 = [1,2,3,4]` and `list2 = [3,4,5,6]` and the condition is difference of 1, then the solution would have the pairs arranged in a list [element from `list1`, element from `list2`, difference]. The solution would be `[[2,3,1],[3,3,0],[3,4,1],[4,3,1],[4,4,0],[4,5,1]]`

Thanks

Comment: Why are two for not an option ? If you need to check the difference between every single pair, that wouldn't be to absurd would it ?

Comment: You need to compare every element of list1 to every element of list2, right? That means you need to execute len(list1)\*len(list2) comparisions. The nested loop is fine.

Comment: Using the two for loops takes too much time if I have a million elements in both the lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to avoid the O(N²) behavior if you sort your lists first (or better yet if your lists are already sorted). Then you can step through them element wise. This would give you O(nLogn) for the sorts plus O(n) to step through the elements. For example:

```
list1 = range(0, 1000000)
list2 = range(999999, 1999999)

def getClose(list1, list2):
    c1, c2 = 0, 0
    while c1 < len(list1) and c2 < len(list2):
        if abs(list1[c1] - list2[c2]) <= 1:
            yield (list1[c1], list2[c2], abs(list1[c1] - list2[c2]))
        if list1[c1] < list2[c2]:
            c1 += 1
        else:
            c2 += 1

for n in getClose(list1, list2):
    print(n)
```

Produces...

> 999998 999999 1
>   999999 999999 0
>   999999 1000000 1

...relatively quickly and much quicker than finding the product first.

Comment: Dammit, I was trying to make my life harder than expected ^^Much easier your way !

Comment: Same idea though, @BornTbeWasted!

Answer (score 3):

### This should work. (Criticism appreciated)

Basically, my idea is to sort the two list O(nlogn), and then go through the list , keeping in memory the distance with the next element, and therefore, not computing all the pairs, but only a subset giving me a O(2*m*n) m being the maximum distance allowed

```
x = sorted([0, 2, 3, 4])
y = sorted([1,3, 4, 5, 6])
index = 0
delta = 1
output = []
j = 0
value_2 = y[0]
no_more = False
number_of_operation = 0
for i,value_1 in enumerate(x[:]):
    print(f'Testing for this {value_1}')
    skip = False
    try:
        next_value_at = x[i+1] - value_1 
        if next_value_at > delta:
            skip = True
            print('We can directly skip to next')
    except:
        print('At the end of list')
    while value_2 - value_1 <= delta:
        number_of_operation+=1
        print(value_1,value_2)
        try:
            if abs(value_1 - value_2) <= delta:
                output += [[value_1,value_2,value_1-value_2]]
            j+=1
            value_2 = y[j]
            print(value_1,value_2) 
            continue
        except:
            no_more = True
            print('end of list')
            break
    if not skip:
        print("Going back")
        j=index
        value_2 = y[index]
    else:
        index = j
    if no_more:
        print('end')
        break
    print(number_of_operation)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy's broadcasting

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6]).reshape(1, -1)
diff = x - y
```

However, you can't avoid N^2 comparisons, only take advantage of numpy's speed optimizations.